# Python PyQT5 выдает warning

Tags: python, pyqt5, pycharm

(Работаю в PyCharm)

Товарищи, помогите разобраться с одной проблемой...
После установки pyqt5 создавал графические приложения и во время их компиляции в pycharm выскакивало следующее предупреждение:

```
QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen DPI.
QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
```

--
как это пофиксить?
в принципе я понял что он хочет, но смутно...
не хотелось бы убирать в коде каждый раз warning'и в любом проекте, который даже может не использовать pyqt5

Comment: В mathplotlib те же warning'и

Answer (score 0):

В **main** добавьте

```
export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=0
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

Пример:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=0
    export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
    export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
    export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

Comment: я видел подобный способ, но не хочется влезать в код и игнорить там подобные предупреждения...